# Filling a square neatly with smaller squares

Tags: java

I am developing a game in which the world is divided up into units called sectors, which the player passes through. Each of these sectors is a different size, and each is divided up into units called SubSectors, which can be different sizes and fill the sector completely. I made a quick drawing of how I would like the generation to work:

[tiles http://jsydie.com/artlib/misc/tiles.gif](http://jsydie.com/artlib/misc/tiles.gif)

EDIT: I am not trying to draw random pictures like this. The SubSector object (represented by the squares above) knows where it's upper-left corner is, and how big it is. I am trying to fit these "squares" onto a grid the size of the parent Sector object.

I am trying to work on the generation for the sectors, but I don't know how to take the next step from here:

```
package world;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Sector {

private static int size;
private static ArrayList<SubSector> sub;

public Sector(int par0) {
    size = par0;
    sub = this.generateSubs();
}

private ArrayList<SubSector> generateSubs() {
    ArrayList<SubSector> out = new ArrayList<SubSector>();

    int side = this.size;
    int spaces = side * side;

    boolean[][] available = new boolean[side][side];

    Random r = new Random();
    int subSide;
    int loc;
    SubSector a;
    boolean anyAvailable = true;

    while(anyAvailable) {
        subSide = r.nextInt(1+side)-1;
        System.out.println(subSide);
        a = new SubSector(subSide);
        loc = r.nextInt(4);
        System.out.println(loc);
        out.add(a);
        if(loc == 0) {
            for(int i=0; i<subSide; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<subSide; j++) {
                    available[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(loc == 1) {
            for(int i=subSide; i>0; i--) {
                for(int j=0; j<subSide; j++) {
                    available[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(loc == 2) {
            for(int i=subSide; i>0; i--) {
                for(int j=subSide; j>0; j--) {
                    available[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(loc == 3) {
            for(int i=0; i<subSide; i++) {
                for(int j=subSide; j>0; j--) {
                    available[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        breakloop:
        for(int i=0; i<side; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<side; j++) {
                if(available[i][j] == true) {
                anyAvailable = true;
                break breakloop;
                }
                else
                    anyAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }


    return out;
}
}
```

I have no idea how to make it check what size SubSectors are now available to it in the remaining space, then create one and place it in a random location.

Comment: Use `switch` instead of consecutive `if`, or at least use `if else`. As to your question: are the squares interactive like buttons, or just drawn like in your example? I would draw them using Swing, as it allows easy managements of the components displayed.

Comment: The squares are SubSector objects, which are the smallest unit of the map. Each SubSector will contain random trees or rocks or hills for the larger ones. I'm trying to fill a Sector of a certain size with SubSectors of smaller sizes in similar fashion to the picture.

Comment: I understood that, but you didn't answer my question: are they interactive or just drawn? You can do this with a `GridBagLayout` or just draw rectangles on a panel.

Comment: Interactive as in being displayed on screen? There won't be a visual of these to use Swing with, so neither.

Comment: Interactive means respond to user clicks. "There won't be a visual of these to use Swing with" - this sentence makes no sense.

Comment: The squares are neither interactive or drawn. I am not dealing with graphics, the picture I made was just a graphic representation of what I want to achieve with coordinates. Each SubSector has an `int size` and a `Point location`, to designate where it will be placed in the space occupied by it's parent Sector. Nothing is being displayed on screen.

Comment: I edited my answer. Tell me if something doesn't function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I created for my own use, but it's modified for your square sub-sectors. It contains a class `Sector` which provides operations on its space and manages its sub-sectors, which are a `SubSector` class. I left the Javadoc in for you. You might want to add checks that the coordinate arguments are inside the sector's space.

```
public class Sector {

    private final int SIZE;
    private int[][] allocationTable;
    private Set<SubSector> subSectors = new HashSet<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new <code>Sector</code> of the specified size.
     * @param size the size of the sector
     */
    public Sector (int size) {

        SIZE = size;
        allocationTable = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a position in the grid is occupied by a {@link SubSector}.
     * @param x the x coordinate
     * @param y the y coordinate
     * @return <code>true</code> if the position is occupied, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public boolean isAllocated(int x, int y) {

        return (allocationTable[x][y] != 0);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the free space originating at the given coordinates. A {@link SubSector} of this
     * maximum size or less can be allocated in this space.
     * @param x the x coordinate origin of the space
     * @param y the y coordinate origin of the space
     * @return the length of contiguous non-allocated space
     */
    public int getNonAllocatedSpaceAt(int x, int y) {

        int space = Math.min(SIZE-x, SIZE-y);
        for (int i = x; i < space +x ; i++) {
            for (int j = y; j < space + y; j++) {
                if (isAllocated(i, j))
                    return Math.max(i - x, j - y);
            }
        }
        return space;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the {@link SubSector} containing the specified coordinate.
     * @param x the x coordinate
     * @param y the y coordinate
     * @return the <code>SubSecotr</code> to which this space is allocated. <code>null</code> if
     * the space is not allocated.
     */
    public SubSector getSubSectorAt(int x, int y) {

        for (SubSector s : subSectors)
            if (s.number == allocationTable[x][y])
                return s;
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the {@link SubSector} specified by its number designation.
     * @param subSector the number designation of the <code>SubSector</code>
     * @return the designated <code>SubSector</code>.  <code>null</code> if the <code>SubSector</code>
     * does not exist.
     */
    public SubSector getSubSector(int subSector) {

        for (SubSector s : subSectors)
            if (s.number == subSector)
                return s;
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Allocates the specified coordinate space to the specified {@link SubSector} and creates a new
     * <code>SubSector</code>. The <code>SubSector</code> must not already exist.
     * @param x the x coordinate origin of the space
     * @param y the y coordinate origin of the space
     * @param size the length of contiguous space to be allocated
     * @param subSector the number designation of the <code>SubSector</code>
     * @return <code>true</code> if the space was allocated, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public boolean allocate(int x, int y, int size, int subSector) {

        if (getNonAllocatedSpaceAt(x, y) < size || !subSectors.add(new SubSector(x, y, size, subSector)))
            return false;
        for (int i = x; i < size + x; i++) {
            for (int j = y; j < size + y; j++) {
                allocationTable[i][j] = subSector;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Frees the space occupied by the specified {@link SubSector} and removes it.
     * @param subSector the <code>SubSector</code> to be removed
     * @return <code>true</code> if the space was deallocated, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public boolean deallocate(int subSector) {

        return remove(getSubSector(subSector));
    }

    /**
     * Frees the space occupied by the {@link SubSector} occupying the specified coordinates.
     * @param x the x coordinate
     * @param y the y coordinate
     * @return <code>true</code> if the space was deallocated, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public boolean deallocate(int x, int y) {

        return remove(getSubSectorAt(x, y));
    }

    private boolean remove(SubSector sub) {

        if (!subSectors.remove(sub))
            return false;
        for (int i = sub.x; i < sub.size + sub.x; i++) {
            for (int j = sub.y; j < sub.size + sub.y; j++) {
                allocationTable[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the allocation table for this <code>Sector</code>.
     * @return the allocation table for this <code>Sector</code>
     */
    public int[][] getAllocationTable() {

        return allocationTable;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the size of this <code>Sector</code>.
     * @return the size of this <code>Sector</code>
     */
    public int getSize() {

        return SIZE;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the (unsorted) {@link Set} of {@link SubSector}s in this <code>Sector</code>.
     * @return the <code>Set</code> of <code>SubSector</code>s in this <code>Sector</code>.
     */
    public Set<SubSector> getSubSectors() {

        return subSectors;
    }

    /**
     * A <code>SubSector</code> represents a square-shaped area in its parent {@link Sector}'s space.
     * A <code>SubSector</code> is designated (named) by a number and each parent <code>Sector</code>
     * can only contain one such <code>SubSector</code>.
     * A <code>SubSector</code> can only be created (and removed) by its parent <code>Sector</code>
     * and can never be modified (this prevents synchronizations issues with the allocation table),
     * however, its fields can be accessed directly.
     */
    public class SubSector {

        /** The x coordinate origin of this <code>SubSector</code>. */
        public final int x;
        /** The y coordinate origin of this <code>SubSector</code>. */
        public final int y;
        /** The length of this <code>SubSector</code>. */
        public final int size;
        /** The designation of this <code>SubSector</code>. */
        public final int number;

        private SubSector(int x, int y, int size, int number) {

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.size = size;
            this.number = number;
        }
    }
}
```